# Can you identify these ST brand SMD components?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, stm

Can you identify these ST brand SMD components? They're from a angle decoder circuit with LEDs and relays.[image: this shows 0 ohm across][image: these show mega ohms across]

Answer (score 2):

Used the [The ultimate SMD marking codes database](https://smd.yooneed.one/):

1. Marking code `BEX` : Used by several manufacturers. SM15T39CA from SGS-Thomson Microelectronics. [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1670952.pdf) confirms the marking.
2. Marking code `MEM` : Used by several manufacturers. SM15T24A from SGS-Thomson Microelectronics. [datasheet](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/SGST/SGST-S-A0010165110/SGST-S-A0010335157-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0) confirms the marking.
3. Marking code `MEP` : SM15T27A from SGS-Thomson Microelectronics. [datasheet](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/SGST/SGST-S-A0010165110/SGST-S-A0010335157-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0) (same as for SM15T24A) confirms the marking.

Comment: Thank you so much you're the best!